# How to make matrix to 1+j, 1-j, -1+j, -1-j in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I have a 4x4 double matrix A

```
 1+2i   2-1i  -3-2i  -1+4i

 3-1i  -3+2i   1-3i  -1-3i   

 4+3i   3+5i   1-2i  -1-4i  

 4+2i  -5-2i   2+3i   2-1i
```

This is my MATLAB code:

```
for n=1:1:4
for k=1:1:4
    temp=A(n,k);
    rea=real(temp);
    img=imag(temp);
    Distance1(n,k)=sqrt(((rea-1).^2)+((img-1).^2));
    Distance2(n,k)=sqrt(((rea+1).^2)+((img-1).^2));
    Distance3(n,k)=sqrt(((rea+1).^2)+((img+1).^2));
    Distance4(n,k)=sqrt(((rea-1).^2)+((img+1).^2));
    Distance(n,k)=min([Distance1(n,k); Distance2(n,k); Distance3(n,k); Distance4(n,k)]);
    Decision(n,k)=?
end
end
```

How do I make a decision matrix that should be 1+j, 1-j, -1+j, -1-j like the below example matrix like this?

```
 1+i   1-i  -1-i  -1+i

 1-i  -1+i   1-i  -1-i   

 1+i   1+i   1-i  -1-i  

 1+i  -1-i   1+i   1-i
```

Answer (score 6):

How about?:

```
B = sign(real(A))+sign(imag(A))*1i;
```

Another variant would be:

```
B = complex(sign(real(A)),sign(imag(A)));
```